# Should this question be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, re-open

Given the comments, should this question be reopened [Is |A| < |B| possible if A->B is surjective?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460276/is-a-b-possible-if-a-b-is-surjective)

With a negative score, no answers and closed it will be automatically deleted, losing the comments in the process.

Comment: I have left a comment, suggesting that Joel post, and answer, an improved version of the question.

Comment: As mentioned in Asaf's comment, the question would be a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65369/half-cantor-bernstein-without-choice anyway if it weren't closed for another reason.